# postgres pg_bulkload c filter function in c programming

Tags: c, postgresql

I'm using postgressql. Reading the data from file and loading it using pg_bulkload- C filter. As per documentation, C filter is much faster than SQL filter.

I'm new to C. Gone through this documentation. Not clear, how to start.

https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/xfunc-c.html.

Can someone kindly guide me to create C code, so that it can be called in postgres function?

Here is the sample data.File has no header.

```
Sample Data:

ABC|20170101|DEF ||GHIJ|KLM



Target Table Definition:

COLA numeric(5,0)

COLB date

COLC text

COLD text

COLE text



First column should be mapped to COLA

Second column should be mapped to COLB

Third column should be mapped to COLD

Fourth column should be mapped to COLC

Fifth column should be mapped to Some default value(column is not present in source)



Transformation:

a)First column should be mapped to COLA. It is numeric in target table. If any alpha-characters were present, default this column with '0'. Otherwise, source value should be moved to table.

b)Second column should be mapped to COLB. TO_DATE function from text format. File will have date format as YYYYMMDD. It should be converted to date.

c)Third column should be mapped to COLD.Need to Trim both leading and trailing spaces.

d)Fourth column should be mapped to COLC. If it NULL, some value should be defaulted.

e)Only few columns from source file should be loaded. In this case, only first four columns should be loaded.

f)Different ordering in source files & target columns.In this case,

        Third column should be mapped to COLD

        Fourth column should be mapped to COLC

g)COLE should be loaded with default value. This column is not present in source file.
```

These transformations, can be handled with query after loading all the data as varchar and nullable. But we need to handle this before loading as like we do in Oracle.

Do you think, these functionalities can be accomplished using C programming? Some standard syntax for writing these functionalities would be greatly helpful.

Thanks